# flutter Firebase messaging duplicating main thread

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to implement Firebase messaging in Flutter, i put my `_firebase.config()` in my HomeScreen(). First time run there's only two main call stack in my VScode [call stack screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An3OF.png)
but everytime i click or open HomeScreen() then the main stack duplicated as many times as i open HomeScreen() as [call stack screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjN4R.png), how to prevent this?

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: Same issue here. Did you ever happen to solve this?

Comment: The "main" call stack is duplicated on every hot reload as well